# How to guarantee that passed object key is callable using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, dependent-type

I'm trying to create a React higher-order component for a specific use-case, the problem is boiling down to the following:

```js
function sample<TObj, P extends keyof TObj, F extends keyof TObj>(
  obj: TObj,
  prop: P,
  setProp: TObj[F] extends (value: TObj[P]) => void ? F : never
) {
  obj[setProp](obj[prop]);
}
```

I want to be able to pass an object, a string which should be a key of that object, and another key of that object but which is required to be a function.

This can be simplified further as such:

```js
function sample2<TObj, F extends keyof TObj>(
  obj: TObj,
  setProp: TObj[F] extends () => void ? F : never
) {
  obj[setProp]();
}
```

It seems to me that because I use the conditional type, it can be guaranteed that `obj[setProp]` will be a function but I get the error:
[image]

```
This expression is not callable.
  Type 'unknown' has no call signatures.ts(2349)
```

As can be seen below, the function will error if it will be called with a key that doesn't respect the requirement. But that same requirement doesn't seem to be applied inside the function.

I understand that this could be seen as a XY problem, but it got me really interested in whether there is a way to make this specific problem work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the implementation of `sample2()`, the type `TObj[F] extends () => void ? F : never` is an unresolved conditional type.  That is, it's a conditional type that depends on a currently-unspecified generic type parameter to be resolved.  In such cases, the compiler generally doesn't know what to do with it and treats it as essentially opaque. (See [microsoft/TypeScript#23132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23132) for some discussion of this.) In particular it doesn't realize that `TObj[Tobj[F] extends ()=>void ? F : never]` will ultimately have to resolve to some subtype of `()=>void`.

In general I'd avoid conditional types entirely unless they are necessary.  The compiler can more easily understand and infer from [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) like `Record<K, V>`:

```
function sample2<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Record<K, () => void>>(
  obj: T,
  prop: K
) {
  obj[prop]();
}
```

And that behaves similarly when you call it:

```
const obj2 = {
  func() { console.log("func") },
  prop: 42
};
sample2(obj2, "func"); // okay, 
//sample2(obj, "prop"); // error
//      ~~~ <-- number is not assignable to ()=>void
```

---

EDIT: to address the original `sample()`, I'd use this definition:

```
function sample<
  PK extends PropertyKey,
  FK extends PropertyKey,
  T extends Record<PK, any> & Record<FK, (v: T[PK]) => void>
>(
  comp: T,
  prop: PK,
  setProp: FK
) {
  comp[setProp](comp[prop]);
}

const obj = {
  func(z: number) { console.log("called with " + z) },
  prop: 42
}
```

which, I think, also behaves how you'd like:

```
sample(obj, "prop", "func"); // called with 42
sample(obj, "prop", "prop"); // error!
//     ~~~ <-- number not assignable to (v: number)=>void
sample(obj, "func", "func"); // error!
//     ~~~ <-- (v: number)=>void not assignable to number
```

---

Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAZwIYFsAOAbApgJgB4BpRXADylzABNlEAFAJzk1yagE9jdOAaRABUylanUQAlXBDhMaJAQAoAlIgC8APkQA3ODBoaNigLAAoRIjgAjAFYAuIXzMXMLTA+JnVAb2eXbANqurAC6KgDcZgC+ZmYyYMhQ-jb46oi+5oigkCrpiPHIcHgAdNhwAOaKAETZEFWqUU6Zwe6IACz40ZGmaFh4+IrWKQI14HXK4YgA9FOWANao-IhmM704BIO2Iy31kzNkTCxMK7MWZwB+l4iEALQ3iGAg6FbsiDD0YHBJqMjIMOVgVBWPCIKBwRAqTS6fSxUy1WAIFAYdaEPwMUgUKi0ejMVjsLg8fh+ABiGNE2MYbnx3F4TQswkxYnoUhkckI6IEqDAnC0ADJJNJZPJSUptA5BAF0SFVJodHoDGYjH4ZFhxXTEC0HBy-MhcFBca1SV50sq4FgArr9W4wirMEFrRNorC4ghEsk0hkLLVFAAvByPZ7sHz5V1FXClCrVCCobB4GiIADuMCgAAtEFVEABqRA+hrqzXtTqmGKmMxrPCbGzbNxVEa1XbTWbR2O4eNJ1OFsvIitDausWvpnYTRsHI4AQhOZwsl3O1zuDyeLyYDy+iB+fwBQJBYIhYoXgaYyih8q7fVwlbrYwHo0gDf27HHk6nM7n90Ue4DS6PGmh8c+31+f5AWBXBQXBT92FhIA)

Comment: This solves the second sample code. Although the main problem is that I want to pass 2 strings which should be dependently typed. I've tried doing it like this:

```typescript
function sample<
  Val,
  P extends PropertyKey,
  F extends PropertyKey,
  TObj extends { [key in P]: Val } & { [key in F]:(value: Val) => void }
>(comp: TObj, prop: P, setProp: F) {
  comp[setProp](comp[prop]);
}
```

But then, when it's called, `sample()` infers the `Val` type as `unknown`

Comment: This is perfect. Somehow it didn't occur to me that it is possible to use a type argument in its own definition.